# How to add metadata to AAC files recorded with AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: ios, metadata, avaudiorecorder, aac

Is there any way to set metadata like `artist`, `title`, `genre` etc. for an AAC file recorded with `AVAudioRecorder`?

For MP3 files there is the [ID3 tag](http://id3.org/). However, I haven't been able to find an equivalent for AAC files. I have searched through the Apple Developer Docs without success but there must be *some* way to set those attributes because when playing an AAC file downloaded from iTunes in an audio player like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) or [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) it does recognize the metadata and even the album art.

*(For recording the AAC files I use the code from Apple's [Multimedia Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW14).)*

Comment: Do you mean a naked `AAC` packet stream or `AAC` in `m4a`?

Comment: Currently I am only using plain AAC but if there is a way to put that AAC file in an m4a container and write the metadata to that file I'll be fine with that.

Comment: I don't think plain `AAC` supports metadata, you'll probably have to switch to m4a.

Comment: If you're using `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` and set the file extension to `.m4a` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add metadata to your audio file when using `AVAudioRecorder`. I think you will have to use an extra `AVAssetExportSession` pass to do that, like is done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918657/adding-metadata-to-aac-m4a-via-avassetexportsession)